# Writing to pipe within a struct failed

Tags: c, process, pipe, shared-memory

I have a struct with the following data members

```
struct process{
    char *arg1;
    char *arg2;
    int fd[2];
    int shmID;
};
```

I initialize a struct of process named process1 with arg1, arg2 and shmID, shmId is the id of a shared memory process I generated with shmget

I then create a pipe from the array stored in my struct with the following code

```
if(pipe(process1.fd) < 0){
       printf("Pipe Failed\n");
       exit(1);
}
```

I then call a function and pass in the address of the struct I just created and initialized, the name of the struct is now 'unit'. I fork the process within the function and if its the parent I close the read end, write to the pipe and then close the write end, and in the child I close the write end and read from the pipe.

However nothing ever gets written to the pipe

```
    int val = 12;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    // If pid is less than 0 the fork failed
    if(pid < 0){
            printf("Fork Failed\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    // Parent Code
    else if(pid > 0){
            close(unit->fd[0]);
            write(unit->fd[1], &val, sizeof(int));
            close(unit->fd[1]);

           ....additional code (I can add if needed, it just waits for the return of the child)

    }
    // In Child
    else if(pid == 0){
            close(unit->fd[1]);
            char str[8];
            sprintf(str, "%d", unit->fd[0]);
            execlp("./program2","programName",unit->arg1,unit->arg2,str, NULL);
    }
```

Comment: please post something we could compile

Comment: How exactly do you detect that "nothing ever gets written to the pipe"? You should check the return code of all non-void functions like `write`. Please [edit] your question to add information. Don't use comments to answer.

Comment: perhaps you're missing a call to dup2?! How are you reading from the pipe anyhow?

Comment: Pipes don't know that they're inside structs. You either have a struct problem, or a pipe problem - there is no interaction between these things. Have you tried to figure out which?

Comment: (actually pipes *can't be* inside structs. `fd` stores two numbers, which are the ID numbers for a pipe, it doesn't actually store a pipe)

Comment: Write returns a 4, Im assuming this is an error code of EDQUOT
The user's quota of disk blocks on the file system containing the file referred to by fd has been exhausted
Previusly I had a problem with shmget where it said "No space left on device" but reseting my computer fixed that error
How can I resolve this error?